# Get the height of an children element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dynamic, height

Hello i will set the height for my div into state.

i tried get the whole height by `get window.innerHeight`this worked fine but i cant access the children of my div, i also try `document.getElementById('masonryParent')` i get also the right result but how i can access the div bellow. Any suggestions?

```
 this.setState({
      width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight
    });
```

[image]

Comment: offsetHeight? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

Comment: what are you trying to achieve here? resize the height of a child? 
have you tried the CSS way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('masonryParent').children[0].style.height
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery you can you this :

$('.masonryParent div').style.height

Comment: im using react but solved it : i . added an ref to my div and so on i can access it by : this.style.refs.masonryContainer.clientHeight